# Efficient way in R to count lines per ID on sliding time window?

Tags: r, dataset, sliding-window

Is there any function from any package that calculates how many times an ID from a line appears on the last x hours. I'll call this 'velocity'.

The target column that I do want to calculate is represented by 'VEL_7H'. In other words, how many times the ID appeared on the last 7 hours?

```
ID        TIME                   VEL_7H
1144727   2016-04-01 09:56:12    0
1144727   2016-04-01 15:16:03    1
1144727   2016-04-01 15:26:14    2
1144727   2016-04-02 09:48:48    0
1799567   2016-04-14 14:41:06    0
1799567   2016-04-14 17:51:06    1
2067650   2016-04-17 12:34:52    0
```

Is there a function using time and ID vectors, and a specified range, that gives the VEL_7H column?

Comment: Could you provide a `dput(your_example)` so it's easier to copy-paste into R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximize performance, I think [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org/) is appropriate:

```
library(Rcpp);
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1144727L,1144727L,1144727L,1144727L,1799567L,1799567L,2067650L),TIME=as.POSIXct(c('2016-04-01 09:56:12','2016-04-01 15:16:03','2016-04-01 15:26:14','2016-04-02 09:48:48','2016-04-14 14:41:06','2016-04-14 17:51:06','2016-04-17 12:34:52')));
cppFunction('
    IntegerVector countTrailingIDs(IntegerVector ids, DoubleVector times, double window ) {
        IntegerVector res(ids.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i) {
            int id = ids[i];
            double trailTime = times[i]-window;
            for (int j = i-1; j >= 0 && ids[j] == id && times[j] >= trailTime; --j)
                ++res[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
');
df$VEL_7H <- countTrailingIDs(df$ID,df$TIME,60*60*7);
df;
##        ID                TIME VEL_7H
## 1 1144727 2016-04-01 09:56:12      0
## 2 1144727 2016-04-01 15:16:03      1
## 3 1144727 2016-04-01 15:26:14      2
## 4 1144727 2016-04-02 09:48:48      0
## 5 1799567 2016-04-14 14:41:06      0
## 6 1799567 2016-04-14 17:51:06      1
## 7 2067650 2016-04-17 12:34:52      0
```

Note that the function requires `ids` and `times` to be ordered according to id and then time.

Comment: Wow. Pretty fast and simple (computed 1.6M velocities instantly). Thank you for the solution, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a classic split-apply-combine approach in base R to first split the data frame by ID, add up the amount of entries in the last 7 hours, then create a new column with the values:

```
sdf <- split(df, df$ID)
last7 <- function(df) sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum(df[i, "TIME"] - df[1:i, "TIME"] <= 60*60*7) - 1L)
df$VEL_7H <- unlist(sapply(sdf, last7))
df
#        ID                TIME VEL_7H
# 1 1144727 2016-04-01 09:56:12      0
# 2 1144727 2016-04-01 15:16:03      1
# 3 1144727 2016-04-01 15:26:14      2
# 4 1144727 2016-04-02 09:48:48      0
# 5 1799567 2016-04-14 14:41:06      0
# 6 1799567 2016-04-14 17:51:06      1
# 7 2067650 2016-04-17 12:34:52      0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is good to see these base R functions providing simple solutions. I still think that is strange that there is no function from some package doing something like this. Upvoted (: